# how to resolve GROUP BY error for ORDER BY column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, timescaledb

I want to select distinct `status` values odered by `time`. However, my following query, which groups by `status` and orders by `time`, shows error like `time` column must be added in group by.

The query I tried is:

```
select "status" 
from detail_status 
where "CAId" = 'test-1234' 
group by "status" 
order by "time" desc 
limit 2;
```

If I add time colum in `GROUP BY` then the result is in wrong order. I need the above query result just grouped by `status` column.

Please, assist for this issue or give another idea for this query concept.

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: Since you group by status, there will be several records and several time value per one status. Which time value do you want to use for sorting? You cannot use all of different values at the same time.

Comment: It will be good if you provide an example of data and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The group by have no sense here. If you want to the 2 last status from detail_status for your table, you have to write the query like that

```
select "status","time" from detail_status where "CAId" = 'test-1234' order by "time" desc limit 2;
```

Maybe that i don't understand what you're looking for ?

Comment: status :
---------
checked
checked
checked
validate
validate

assume that those status value in that table, then i need result was 

status:
--------
checked
validate 

only, that means i need only distinct values only.

Comment: Can you edit your question, add a sample of datas of the table detail_status and the result you want to help us understand your need. thx

Answer (score 0):

To get distinct `status` values ordered by `time` it is necessary to inlude `time` into the result projection of the query. Since several records might correspond to a distinct value of `status` it is necessary to apply an [aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tutorial-agg.html) on `time`, e.g., `MAX`, `AVG`, or `MIN`. So the query might be:

```sql
SELECT "status", MAX("time") AS time
FROM detail_status 
WHERE "CAId" = 'test-1234' 
GROUP BY "status" 
ORDER BY "time" DESC 
LIMIT 2;
```

If you need that the final query contains only `status`, you can nest the above query and project only status, however the order might not be guaranteed.

Comment: you can also use `SELECT DISTINCT ON (status)  * FROM detail_status
WHERE "CAId" = 'test-1234'
ORDER BY status, "time" DESC;`